# Mac based dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dnsmasq

Is it possible to return different IP for same domain based on the Mac(or any other thing) of the client?

For example, I have a `dynamic.test` domain used in localnet, when `userA` queries the IP of `dynamic.test`, the DNS server should return the predefined IP provided by `userA`, and when `userB` queries, the DNS server should return the IP defined by `userB`.

The process is something like this:

```
[userA] # dns-register dynamic.test 10.0.0.100
[userB] # dns-register dynamic.test 10.0.0.101
[userA] # nslookup dynamic.test #==> should give 10.0.0.100
[userB] # nslookup dynamic.test #==> should give 10.0.0.101
[userA] # dns-register dynamic.test 10.0.0.103
[userA] # nslookup dynamic.test #==> should give 10.0.0.103
```

`dns-register` is an example tool provided by THE `DNS server`

Comment: Do you mean only for yourself? Or also for other clients on your LAN? You can change /etc/hosts (use sudo).

Comment: For all employees in my company. and iphone/android phone should also use the domain, so /etc/hosts is not the case.

Comment: You have many clients? You need to install a DNS server. Which can be a bit  complicated. Are all clients MacOS (or also mobiles, windows, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe use MacOS server? That has installed DNS service (BIND). Have a look here: http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/47878/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not directly, but in combination with DHCP, this can be possible. Firs step is configure DHCP for two (or more) pools, they can be in the same subnet and add static reservation from one pool for known MACs.

Second step is configure DNS server which support `view`s, for example BIND, `view` match client by IP od subnet and can return different values for different clients. An example of a `view` Clause from [Pro DNS and BIND](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html):

```
view "trusted" {
 match-clients { 192.168.23.0/24; }; // our network
  recursion yes;
  // other view statements as required
  zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   // private zone file including local hosts
   file "internal/master.example.com";
  };
  // add required zones
 };
view "badguys" {
 match-clients {"any"; }; // all other hosts
 // recursion not supported
 recursion no;
 // other view statements as required
 zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   // public only hosts
   file "external/master.example.com";
  };
  // add required zones
 };
```

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328260/dnsmasq-different-responses-for-specific-mac-addresses) may also be useful...